# Free PDF editor for OS X, as alternative to Adobe Acrobat

Tags: osx, pdf, pdf-editor

I'm looking for an open source (or possibly just freeware) alternative to Adobe Acrobat for Mac.

I want to be able to create, open and edit PDF documents.

I want a fair amount of features (but it doesn't have to actually be as comprehensive as Acrobat.)

Features that should be included are editing the text body of documents, inserting pictures, rotating pictures, resizing pictures, moving pictures within document, and text wrapping.

Comment: What's missing in the native Preview app?

Comment: @MarcoL As its name suggests, it's an app for _viewing_ documents rather than editing them. It really has no significant editing features, except for some really basic ones like rotate page and the ability to mark text with different colors. It doesn't allow you to create or edit PDFs in any real matter. Its's a PDF viewer, not an editor.

Comment: I use it to edit them: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201740

Comment: @MarcoL I didn't know Preview had such features, but it still looks a little too slim for my needs. Can we edit text in the main body, add images, resize images, rotate images, etc? Also, I couldn't figure out how to cut out certain pages with Preview. Neither could I figure out how to merge different documents, etc.

Comment: You can cut out and merge PDF, but not edit as in Acrobat. You can add text in an overlay but it is not the same. Good luck with your research

Comment: **PDFSam**: http://www.pdfsam.org > PDFsam Basic is our free and open source desktop application to split,
> merge, rotate and mix PDF files

Answer (score 1):

I have the following recommendations for you:

[iSkysoft PDF Editor for Mac](https://www.iskysoft.com/edit-pdf/free-pdf-editor-mac.html):

> With this tool, you are able to edit, add, modify and delete texts,
>   graphics and images in PDF format. Besides that, you could also
>   convert your PDF files to Word conveniently as well as annotate and
>   mark all the screen content with its variety of tools.

[PDF Editor Mac](http://www.pdfeditormac.com/):

> PDF Editor Mac is a software application on Mac OS X that allows users
>   to add text, insert images, put watermarks to label their copyright,
>   changing font size and color, and perform other changes of a PDF
>   document.
>
> After adding text and images, you can change the text font and color,
>   resize the image height and width or move them as well. If you need to
>   delete some words or text from the PDF, simply click on the eraser
>   tool then erase. Rotating certain pages and modifying document layout
>   is also important so as multiple drawing tools like lines, brushes,
>   horizontal lines or vertical lines. Better than normal PDF Readers and
>   Annotators, PDF Editor Mac can permanently save the modified PDF
>   content changes.

Some Images:

[image: PDF EDITOR MAC]

Comment: The latter seems pretty decent. As for the first one: It doesn't really seem to be free. They've got this "Free trial" thing.